# Install Ansible in Windows, using Git-bash

Tags: windows-7, git-bash, ansible

I am trying to install the [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/how-ansible-works) [open source automation platform](https://networklore.com/ansible/) on Windows. There are many guides out there for how to install Ansible using Cygwin (eg. [1](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/running-ansible-within-windows), [2](https://ericsysmin.com/2016/07/28/install-ansible-on-windows/)).

However, I already have Git-Bash installed on Windows 7 (from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)).

Is it possible to install Ansible in Windows, inside Git-Bash.

**EDIT:**

UPDATE:

I had a lot of problems with Cygwin.

1. I installed Cygwin.
2. Then I did `pip install PyYAML, jinja, paramiko, cryptography`, etc. I wanted to install the Ansible dependencies first and then do `pip install ansible` only at the end. It did not install `paramiko` and `cryptography` successfully. Two packages `libffi` and `ncurses` were found to be missing. I re-ran the Cygwin installer and installed `libffi`. I could not find `ncurses`.
3. I restarted Cygwin and re-tried `pip install paramiko cryptography`. They did not install again and gave the same error message that `libffi` and `ncurses` were missing. At that point, I gave up and uninstalled Cygwin. I did not try it again.

**EDIT 2:**
To answer this question, I did this:

- installed [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) on Windows 7
- [created a Virtualbox *buntu VM](https://www.lifewire.com/run-ubuntu-within-windows-virtualbox-2202098) with [LUbuntu 17.10](http://lubuntu.net/)
- installed all available system updates
- (optional) installed [VirtualBox Linux guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idm2096) (section 4.2.2.1 steps 2. and 3.)
- `pip install ansible` worked successfully
- installed text editor in VM

  With this setup, I do everything related to Ansible directly in the LUbuntu VM.

Comment: Git Bash is not a full Linux environment, it is specifically built to run Git on Windows, not a general purpose environment.  For general purpose use an environment like Cygwin or the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

Comment: While WSL is Linux shell it does have limitations and doesn’t support everything at this time. Git-Bash isn’t a Cygwin replacement nor is it advertised as one.

Comment: Thanks to both. Can't do it with Git-Bash.:( OK, my question is answered.

Answer (score 4):

Git-Bash is insufficient to install ansible, it is lack of build tools.

I recommend you try msys2(which git-bash base on), once install all ansible build dependencies, you can install ansible just by `pip install ansible`.

Comment: Hey thanks! I will have to try this....it looks very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Working instructions are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596203/cygwin-how-to-install-ansible

Basically you install Cygwin and build tools, and available Python modules. Then you run:

```
pip2 install ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows Subsystem for Linux and Ansible is working great there. You can quickly give it a try by enabling the feature via PowerShell script: 
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux`
and then go to Microsoft Store and choose your distribution:

- Ubuntu
- OpenSUSE
- SLES
- Kali Linux
- Debian GNU/Linux

Comment: Yup, good point that is yet another option for Windows 10. Here I was referring to Windows 7 specifically, which was my reason to try Cygwin (unsuccessfully) and gitbash (before going with the VM option), though the options for Windows 10 are certainly more convenient.

Comment: I think you were downvoted because you gave a link-only answer. You need to copy the exact steps needed in to your answer. The reason is that the link may die and then your answer becomes blank. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer